# AWS S3 get bucket acceleration status request is not scalable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, throttling

There is service named SDK Back-end, which is running in AWS EKS.
The service has API which generates STS token.
One of the steps of the API is checking S3 bucket acceleration status.

```
  lazy val proxyConf: ProxyConfiguration = ProxyConfiguration.builder()
    .host(sys.env("EGRESS_PROXY_HOST"))
    .port(sys.env("EGRESS_PROXY_PORT").toInt)
    .scheme("http")
    .build()

  val httpClient: Resource[IO, SdkAsyncHttpClient] =
      Resource.fromAutoCloseable(IO(NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder()
        .maxConcurrency(10)
        .proxyConfiguration(proxyConf)
        .build()))

  val getAWSS3Client: Resource[IO, S3AsyncClient] = httpClient.map(c =>
    S3AsyncClient.builder().httpClient(c).region(Region.of(
      sys.env.getOrElse("AWS_REGION", "us-west-2")
    )).build()
  )

  override def getBucketAccelerationStatus(bucket: String): IO[BucketAccelerateStatus] = for {
    _ <- logger.info(s"Getting acceleration status for bucket $bucket ...")
    req = GetBucketAccelerateConfigurationRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).build()
    status <- getAWSS3Client.use(s3 => IO.fromFuture(IO(s3.getBucketAccelerateConfiguration(req).asScala)).map(resp => resp.status()))
  } yield status
```

`EGRESS_PROXY_HOST` is Route53 record which leads to VPC Endpoint.

I'm trying to load test the API.
The test case consists of 40 users which send the API call during 5 minutes.
There is 1 POD of the service.
Run result is as follows.
[image]
The `getBucketAccelerationStatus` method call is taking around 50ms.

Then I scale number of service's PODs up from 1 to 5.
And running the test once again.
The result is as follows.
[image]

The `getBucketAccelerationStatus` method call is taking around 2000ms.

So, scaling the service up makes response time in 2.5 time worse.

I have checked Monitoring tab of VPC Endpoint used as proxy for get bucket acceleration status request.
[image]

It shows that 5 replicas (PODs) of the service are creating less connections and traffic.

I'm suspecting throttling on S3 side, but don't see any errors (503 Slow down) in the service's logs on this matter as stated https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/http-5xx-errors-s3.

So, it's not clear for me why scaling number of service's PODs up from 1 to 5 make the call `getBucketAccelerationStatus` slower.

Comment: This is just a guess, I haven't asked in rePost or contacted AWS support:  I wouldn't be surprised if getting / setting the bucket state isn't designed to scale up and is expensive.  Amazon might expect you to set it and keep it set for long periods not have multiple clients toggling it frequently, and/or it might involve locking/the equivalent of critical sections.

Comment: @DaveS thank you for the clue. I've sent the question to AWS support. I'll keep you posted on update.